# Make a RDD from Class

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I can create RDD if i have List and perform required operation like

```
val li = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
val rdd = sc.parallelize(li, 5)
val rddm =rdd.map(x =>x * 2).map(println(_)).collect()
```

But when i try to create RDD from a class, it gives error stating **object not serializable (class: BAT1, value: BAT1@78f84d5)**. My code is

```
object sparkBAT {
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
 val N = 10
 val d = 5
 val MinVal = -10
 val MaxVal =  10
 val conf = new  SparkConf().setMaster(locally("local")).setAppName("spark Demo")
 val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

 val ba = List.fill(N)(new BAT(d, MinVal, MaxVal))

 val rdd = sc.parallelize(ba, 5)
 rdd.map(x=> (x.BestFitness ,(x.fitness,x.position))).take(5)
 rdd.mapPartitions( y => y.map{x => println(x.position, x.fitness)})
 }
}
class BAT ( dim:Int  ,  min:Double  ,  max:Double){
val random = new Random()
var position      : List[Double]      =   List.fill(dim) (random.nextDouble() * (max-min)+min )
var velocity      :List[Double]       =   List.fill(dim)( math.random)
var PulseRate     : Double            =   0.1
var LoudnessRate  :Double             =   0.95
var frequency     :Double             =   math.random
var fitness       :Double             =   math.random
var BestPosition  :List[Double]       =   List.fill(dim)(math.random)
var BestFitness   :Double             =   math.random 
}
```

How can i create RDD from **BAT** class?

Comment: Add `extends Serializable` to your class. I would also suggest using Kryo

Comment: @NirHedvat can you please explain what is **Kryo**

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo. If you're using RDD (as opposed to DataFrame, for instance) it's better to register your classes.